# Using React Native iOS dependency in Objective-c

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I currently have the following dependency in a ReactNative project's `package.json`:

```
"vital-health-react-native": "file:../packages/vital-health-react-native"
```

This package has a `.podspec` with the following dependency:

```
s.dependency "VitalHealthKit", "~> 0.7.7"
```

Because I am dealing with HealthKit and background delivery, I need to be able to call a method from this dependency inside the `AppDelegate.mm`.

I have tried everything to import `VitalHealthKit` in the `.mm` and even in the `.h`, but the dependency is never found. The spec for `VitalHealthKit` can be found [here](https://github.com/tryVital/vital-ios/blob/main/VitalHealthKit.podspec).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve not done sub-dependency imports myself but I think one would need to add the pod to the app project’s Podfile like so

```
pod 'VitalHealthKitRN', path: "#{path_to_packages} /packages/vital-health-react-native/VitalHealthRN.podspec"
```

Having done that, if one still can’t import VitalHealthKit in the app, it might be necessary to reference VitalHealthKit native pod in the Podfile directly, either in a usual way (that might create a conflict of dependency versions with the RN pod) or using a local relative path, similar to the above. Might also have to `use_frameworks!` if you don’t already to avoid double-linking vital health kit. Hope this helps.